# Windows Backup (2008 R2) recovery and timezone

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, timezone

does difference between timezones on Windows Server 2008 where backup was made and reovery console makes difference? Recovery console (wbadmin from command line too) is not finding any backup on local hard drive connected to server.

Thanks

EDIT: I'm working on Windows Server 2008 R2

EDIT2: This is not related to timezone. When I connected backup hard drive from Windows 2008 R2 Release Candidate recovery console runned from RTM system version DVD found stored backups from it without problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot restore a backup from a local drive.

Comment: I'm trying to restore from special hard drive which is used by Windows Backup to store backups. I forgot to add that I'm trying to restore Windows Server 2008 R2.

Interesting thing is when I connect backup hard drive from Windows Server 2008 R2 Release Candidate. Recovery console runned from Windows 2008 R2 RTM DVD is finding this backup without problems.

Comment: What do you mean by special? If it is external than it should work, but if it is local storage it isn't supported by Windows Backup.